# Change \jot length inside nested aligned environment

Tags: formatting, align, lengths

I'm using `aligned` environments inside an `align*` environment for some custom alignment. I would like the space between lines of the `align*` environment to be bigger than the space between lines of the `aligned` environment, but it seems that changing the `\jot` length does not have an effect when done inside the `align*` environment. I.e., the following does not give the desired result.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\setlength{\jot}{1em}
\begin{align*}
True &\mapsto [true] && \text{\small{\textsc{Rule 1}}} \\
e_1 \operatorname{or} e_2 &\mapsto
\setlength{\jot}{0.1em}\begin{aligned}[t]
\textbf{let }&e_1 \mapsto [a], \\
&e_2 \mapsto [b] \\
\textbf{in }&[a \lor b]
\end{aligned} && \text{\small{\textsc{Rule 2}}}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image: result]

The spacing between the lines of `Rule 2` is the same as between `Rule 1` and `Rule 2`. Is there a way to do this without having to set the length manually at every line with `\\[-0.9em]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting `\jot` before `\begin{aligned}` seems to be too late. You can use `\openup` instead.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\setlength\jot{2ex}
\begin{align*}
\mathit{True} &\mapsto [\mathit{true}] && \textsc{\small Rule 1} \\
e_1 \operatorname{or} e_2 &\mapsto
\openup-0.5\jot
\begin{aligned}[t]
\textbf{let }&e_1 \mapsto [a], \\
&e_2 \mapsto [b] \\
\textbf{in }&[a \lor b]
\end{aligned} && \textsc{\small Rule 2}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

A few notes. If you want “True” and “true” to be in italics, use `\mathit` as shown; for ”Rule 1” and ”Rule 2” the input is much simpler.

Comment: Thanks for the tips!